# change color tabbar icons iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios5, uitabbar

I am able to restyle the UITabBar with the following commands

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

But how can I set the imageTintColor when the tab isn't selected. The default color is grey and I want to change this to blue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Apple docs UITabBar Class Reference:

> If you want to also customize the unselected image appearance, you must sent setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: to individual tab bar items.

Answer (score 3):

> In AppDlegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
return YES;
}
```